# Generate sequence of time periods in R as strings (non-standard)

Tags: r, date

I have a worksheet that accepts only a specific format for displaying Year-Month period.

`2018M01` means January of 2018 
`2019M05` means May of 2019, etc.

I need to specify the Start period and the End Period, then generate a sequence of dates compatible with this format.

Here is an example:

```
start <- "2015M04" 
end <- "2016M07"
```

Result:

`[1] "2015M04"  "2015M05"  "2015M06"  "2015M07"  "2015M08"  "2015M09" 
 [7] "2015M010" "2015M011" "2015M012" "2016M01"  "2016M02"  "2016M03" 
[13] "2016M04"  "2016M05"  "2016M06"  "2016M07"`

I tried to figure it out by doing the following (but ran out of ideas, because my period usually never starts or ends with `M01` and `M12`, respectively

```
startyear <- 2015

endyear <- 2016

diffyear <- 2016-2015

seq_year <- rep(seq(from = startyear, to = endyear, by = 1), each = 12)

seq_quarters <- rep(seq(from = 1, to = 12, by = 1),  diffyear)

paste0(seq_year, "M","0", seq_quarters)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work:

```
start <- "2015M04" 
end <- "2016M07"


date_vec <- seq.Date(
         from = as.Date(paste0(gsub("M", "-", start),"-01")),
         to   = as.Date(paste0(gsub("M", "-", end),  "-01")),
         by = "m")

format(date_vec, "%YM%m")
     [1] "2015M04" "2015M05" "2015M06" "2015M07" "2015M08" "2015M09" "2015M10" "2015M11" "2015M12" "2016M01" "2016M02" "2016M03"
[13] "2016M04" "2016M05" "2016M06" "2016M07"
```

Comment: Thank you!

Do you have an idea how to generate analogous solution if Q for Quarters is used?

`start <- "2015Q2"`
 `end <- "2016Q4"`

`[1] "2015Q2"  "2015Q3"  "2015Q4"  "2016Q1"  "2016Q2"  "2016Q3"  "2016Q4"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use function:

```
date_seq <- function(start,end) {
  date_vec <- seq.Date(
    from = as.Date(paste0(gsub("M", "-", start),"-01")),
    to   = as.Date(paste0(gsub("M", "-", end),  "-01")),
    by = "m")
  return(format(date_vec, "%YM%m"))
}

date_seq("2015M04" ,"2019M08")
```